# jquery get responseText undefined yet web inspector shows xhr object with data and in inspector it also shows response text for the object

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have tried to find a working solution by browsing the topics here but nothing works. 
the problem is as follows:

i have this piece of code

```
    function get_states(data){
    data( $.get("url") );
}

$(function(){

    get_states(function(data){
        console.log(data.responseText);

    });
```

I have the following issue: 
If I change the console.log to only show (data), it shows an object which has the responseText populated with the values I need. Also, the web inspector resources shows an xhr response with the data I need. however, calling on the data.responseText shows undefined.

I tried multiple workarounds, as in: $.ajax with type get and success function (for some reason the success function doesn't trigger), function.done(function(data){}) etc. They either show object or undefined.

It is true however that the http shows an error while trying to access it, but the page source has the data I need (it just doesnt display it). And also the xhr (when viewing in the inspector) has the data I need. 
Could it be that due to the hhtp error I cannot get the responseText?

Answer (score 0):

$.get is async operation.

try this :

```
  function get_states(data)
   {
      return  $.get("url") ;
   }

$(function(){

    get_states().done(function(data)
      {
        console.log(data);
      }
});
```

Comment: I know its async, that's why I'm doing the callback (btw I saw that you deleted your comment). That callback should trigger when the function is populated. So when it passes the data it should be filled (which is because the object does have the responseText with data), but on calling the data.responseText it shows undefined. this puzzles me. Your function doesnt return anything.

Comment: What do you mean by _Your function doesnt return anything_ ?  I run the getStates() method which returns deferred object which then  - when resolved ( done) i check its data.

Comment: I wasnt sayin your code doesnt generally work, just in this case it doesnt. It doesnt print anything unfortunately. And i did try earlier with $.ajax(...).done(). and with successes (as I said) buy it didnt return anything. So my guess is that it is related with the error on the webpage that I try to access.

Comment: @RazvanSoneriu if you have a url - i'll be happy to help

Comment: http://www.ppt.ro/Admin/Public/DataManagement/PublishingOutput.aspx?PubID=1 if you look in the page source you can see that the page source has the info i need...the rendered page doesnt. could it be that the issue?